# cakephp: how do you load a behavior from a plugin?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

### edit

### I used cake bake to make a new plugin and behavior (using --plugin) and it worked. Not sure what I missed.

I'm trying to load the behavior of a plugin. I'm trying to do this with a plugin I wrote for my own use, but I get the same problem when trying to load someone else's.

For example loading https://github.com/Xety/Cake3-Upload

I know you should normally use composer, but this is the way I would load my own plugin.

1. copy the plugin to `\app\plugins\Cake3Upload`
2. load the plugin in `bootstrap.php` using

   `Plugin::load('Cake3Upload', ['autoload' => true]);`
3. access the behavior in my model's `MyModelTable.php` `initialize` function

`$this->addBehavior('Cake3Upload.Upload');`

I then get the following error:

> Missing Behavior
>
> Cake3Upload.UploadBehavior could not be found.
>
> Make sure your plugin was loaded from config\bootstrap.php and
>   Composer is able to autoload its classes, see Loading a plugin and
>   Plugins - autoloading plugin classes
>
> Error: Create the class UploadBehavior below in file:
>   \app\plugins\Cake3Upload\src\Model\Behavior\UploadBehavior.php

```
use Cake\ORM\Behavior;

class UploadBehavior extends Behavior
{

}
```

Comment: Have you read [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes) as the error message suggests?

Comment: yes. that's why I tried `['autoload' => true]`

Answer (score 0):

And what about namespaces ? If u wont use composer u must build the same files tree.

I think it's just about the uploadBehavior have this namespace:

```
namespace Xety\Cake3Upload\Model\Behavior;
```

then u only have to follow the plugin doc:

```
Plugin::load('Xety/Cake3Upload');
```

and

```
$this->addBehavior('Xety/Cake3Upload.Upload');
```

Add 'Xety/' maybe

Comment: I have the same error when I bake my own plugin, so I don't think it has to do with name spacing.